# infiniteScroll with pagerAddRows but Timeago only work for the repeat limit not more

Tags: xpages, infinite-scroll, timeago

I use the [Timeago for Xpages](http://www.openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Timeago%20for%20XPages) and the [inifinite scrolling Custom Control](http://openntf.org/s/simple-custom-control-to-add-inifinite-scrolling-to-repeat-or-views).
If I use ones of them it is good. But if use both not good. The timeago only works on the entries in the repeatlimit. If I scrolling down the other one dont have a Timeago date.
The Timeago called by a dojo.addOnLoad function. For the first time okay. What event or function must I use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the script when the infinity scroll button is clicked to add the scripts for the Timeago custom control.

I added the Timeago script inside the infinite scroll script and after 500ms (the time until the server responds and fetches more rows) it will re-parse all timeago classes.

```
    <xp:scriptBlock id="scriptBlock1">
    <xp:this.value><![CDATA[$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()) {
       $(".infiniteScroll ul li a").click();
    setTimeout(function(){ 
        dojo.query(".timeago").forEach( function(el) {
          var timeagoWidget= dijit.getEnclosingWidget(el);
          if(!timeagoWidget){
            timeagoWidget = new timeago.Timeago({}, el);
          }

          //refresh timeago
          timeagoWidget.refresh();
        });
    },500);
    }
});]]></xp:this.value>
  </xp:scriptBlock>
```

Another option is hijack the partial refresh and always re-rerender the timeago scripts. How you can hijack it is explained [here](http://xpageswiki.com/web/youatnotes/wiki-xpages.nsf/dx/Work_with_events_and_partial_or_full_refresh).

Comment: I have a problem with the ID for the Widget. I cannot calculate the id of the computed text. If I try to put a composite data to the id it said that is null. But it dont. Error: Tried to register widget with id==timeago_Timeago_0 but that id is already registered

Comment: Check out the edited code. Previously it was rebuilding timeago widgets on domNodes that where already widgets... sorry for that ;-)

Comment: Not for that. I try it!